# How can I get element at a particular index in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have stored three json objects in elasticsearch, each object has a `title` and `projects` array.

```
{"name": "haris","projects": [{"title": "Splunk"},{"title": "QRadar"},{"title": "LogAnalysis"}]}

{"name": "khalid","projects": [{"title": "MS"},{"title": "Google"},{"title": "Apple"}]}

{"name": "Hamid","projects": [{"title": "Toyota"},{"title": "Honda"},{"title": "Kia"}]}
```

I have written a query to extract a particular object by `_id` and its specific property `projects`

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/jsontest/_search?pretty' -d '{"query" : { "match" : {"_id":"AV1kzzZqAzHWQ2S7B8f1"} }, "_source": ["projects"]}'
```

As expected it returns projects object

`{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "jsontest",
        "_type" : "json",
        "_id" : "AV1kzzZqAzHWQ2S7B8f1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "projects" : [{"title" : "Splunk"},{"title" : "QRadar"},{"title" : "LogAnalysis"}
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}`

**Question**: is there a way to retrieve value at a particular index of `projects`? This is dummy data, in my real scenario `projects` can have a large number of elements and each element itself is a json object with a lot of properties. I only need to retrieve value at certain index of `projects`.

Comment: just to be clear you want to return a certain field from one of the elements of the projects array but you don't want to return the whole project array element? if this is the case you achieve this by just extending your query with `inner_hits` [Elasticsearch Inner Hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits)

Comment: @UlugToprak No, I do not want certain field from one of the elements, I want complete element of array

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i would do.

First the mapping

```
PUT test/my_objects/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "name":{
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    },
    "projects": {
      "type": "nested"
    }
  }
}
```

Second Projects are indexed

```
PUT test/my_objects/1111
{
"name": "haris",
      "projects": [
              {"title": "Splunk"},
              {"title": "QRadar"},
              {"title": "LogAnalysis"}
 ]
}
```

Finally the aggregation query

```
GET test/my_objects/_search

{
  "aggs": {
    "by_name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_project": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "projects"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "by_title": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "projects.title"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

its not tested and a bit tedious because of the nested aggs but should work if you manipulate it further for you requirements